# AWS micro instance has 95% + and Nodejs app is not accessible in the browser

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

The CPU usage is consistently over 95% for the NodeJs app. Even though the nodejs app is running, when I try to access it in the browser, its not accessible at all.

I'm running on a Micro instance for testing purposes.

Why is this happening and what might be a solution for this?

Comment: Sounds like it could be simply that your app has a bug -- perhaps your code has an endless/infinite loop that occurs in a certain condition?

Comment: I upgraded to M3-small, and the app is running fine now. I will to check on the usage limits for a t1 micro instance.

Comment: Ah, okay, good.  t1.micro was EC2's first attempt at a low-cost, burstable instance, and is only suited to extremely light workloads. I never use them any more and wouldn't recommend them, they have essentially a "brick wall" of low performance when throttling kicks in, and the algorithm makes them not very useful.  The newer t2.micro is not only cheaper, but has a far better implementation of burstability, with more graceful degradation and "credit balances" that essentially "reward" you up to 24 hours later with longer bursts of performance for bursts you don't use right now.

Comment: P.S. I am right because I found it on the Internet.  Seriously, though, the EC2 documentation that explains how the t1.micro works also suggests that you should consider the t2 class instead. *"The t1.micro is a previous generation instance and it has been replaced by the t2.micro, which has a much better performance profile. We recommend using the t2.micro instance type instead of the t1.micro."* http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html

Answer (score 1):

t1.micro and all t2 instances use a burstable CPU model. While idle, you build up credits. When active you use credits. Once you hit 0, your instance is throttled.

You can confirm this by looking at CPU credit usage and balance in Cloudwatch.

To fix, use a larger instance, maybe t2.small.

Comment: I did upgrade to m3-Small. But the app is still unresponsive. 
1. Nodejs process is running
2. As soon I do forever start app.js, the CPU spikes upto 100%